# R data transformation

Tags: r

I have an R data frame that looks like this:

```
z = as.data.frame(list(Col1=c("a","c","e","g"),Col2=c("b","d","f","h"),Col3=c("1,2,5","3,5,7","9,8","1")))
> z
  Col1 Col2  Col3
1    a    b 1,2,5
2    c    d 3,5,7
3    e    f   9,8
4    g    h     1
```

(The third column is a text column with comma-separated values.)  I would like to convert it to a data frame like this:

```
a    b    1
a    b    2
a    b    5
c    d    3
c    d    5
c    d    7
e    f    9 
e    f    8
g    h    1
```

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this using apply?  I'm close using the command below but it's not quite right.  Any suggestions on more efficient ways to do this would be appreciated as well...

```
> apply(z,1,function(a){ids=strsplit(as.character(a[3]),",")[[1]];out<-c();for(id in ids){out<-rbind(out,c(a[1:2],id))};return(out)})
[[1]]
     Col1 Col2    
[1,] "a"  "b"  "1"
[2,] "a"  "b"  "2"
[3,] "a"  "b"  "5"

[[2]]
     Col1 Col2    
[1,] "c"  "d"  "3"
[2,] "c"  "d"  "5"
[3,] "c"  "d"  "7"

[[3]]
     Col1 Col2    
[1,] "e"  "f"  "9"
[2,] "e"  "f"  "8"

[[4]]
     Col1 Col2    
[1,] "g"  "h"  "1"
```

Comment: I'll also note that I tested the two solutions presented here on a larger real data set, and perhaps no surprisingly, the execution time was pretty much the same.  In case that's useful to anyone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `reshape`or `reshape2`

```
require(reshape2)
merge(cbind(z[,-3], L1=rownames(z)), melt(strsplit(as.character(z$Col3),",")))
```

gives

```
  L1 Col1 Col2 value
1  1    a    b     1
2  1    a    b     2
3  1    a    b     5
4  2    c    d     3
5  2    c    d     5
6  2    c    d     7
7  3    e    f     9
8  3    e    f     8
9  4    g    h     1
```

Comment: Nice!  Both answers work perfectly so it's impossible to choose a "better" one.  Ended up choosing this answer because it pointed me to the `merge` function, which seems like a nice general-purpose tool I need to learn too...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ddply`.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(z, c("Col1", "Col2"), summarize, 
  Col3=strsplit(as.character(Col3),",")[[1]]
)
```